# How do I decide which track mode to use for different ampere ratings

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, proteus

There are different tracks in proteus ARES like T15, T40 etc. What is their unit? How do I decide which track mode to use for different ampere ratings?

Comment: How thick will the copper be on your board? try Googling pcb track width calculators. What are the units used elsewhere in ARES?

Comment: I would almost bet money on those being 0.015" and 0.040" respectively.

Comment: @MattYoung I won't bet against, as you are right.

Answer (score 2):

T15 is `15 mil` width = `0.381mm`. T40 is `40 mil` width=`1.016mm`. To calculate your requirements you can use some online calculators, like [this one](http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2006/01/31/pcb-trace-width-calculator/).

Comment: please note that link uses IPC-2221 . This has been replaced by IPC-2152